# jQuery check if html height is 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css

jQuery('html').css('height') will show height in px. I would like to check if height is set to 100%. Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).height();`  returns height of HTML document and `$(window).height();`    returns height of browser viewport  accord to [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/) so if you compare it to one of these (whichever is suitable for your needs - window is probably better as document may overrun the window)  you can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

yes with `offsetHeight`

Here an example
http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/c9fqstL8/

js

```
var element = document.getElementById('el');
console.log(element.offsetHeight);
```

CSS

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
div{
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This returns number in px and not 100%

Comment: jut divide that result with the height of you container and that will tell you the percentage